# Magento Error : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shoukatt_mgnt1.captcha_log' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, magento, error-handling

I am new to Magento and dont have lot of coding idea.
i installed Magento and then installed my sample data with a new sql file, which made my user name and password of Magento admin panel vanish, so i created my username and password through sql database.

But now when i login in admin panel, i receive error like this "Magento : exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons". but when i refresh the page i can then access my admin panel

I opened the error vile in var/errors which number i received and changed it into xml file.

I am mentioning every thing written in this file, please anyone help me or i will have to install magento again and will lost my all data and configuration

```
a:5:{i:0;s:100:"
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shoukatt_mgnt1.captcha_log' doesn't exist";i:1;s:3388:"
#0 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(63012): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(52694): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(53730): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#4 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(54566): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#5 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(52876): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
#6 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/Mage_Captcha_Model_Resource_Log.php(100): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete('captcha_log', Array)
#7 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer.php(276): Mage_Captcha_Model_Resource_Log->deleteUserAttempts('usman')
#8 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer.php(233): Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer->_resetAttempt('usman')
#9 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(21045): Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer->resetAttemptForBackend(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(21024): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer), 'resetAttemptFor...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('admin_session_u...', Array)
#12 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/Mage_Admin_Model_Session.php(104): Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_u...', Array)
#13 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/Mage_Admin_Model_Observer.php(69): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->login('usman', '86288844', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(21045): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#15 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(21024): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#16 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#17 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(13691): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#18 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#19 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(13571): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#20 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(17927): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#21 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(17484): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/includes/src/__default.php(20061): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 /home4/shoukatt/public_html/mag/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is.

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shoukatt_mgnt1.captcha_log' doesn't exist
```

An extension is attempting to load the table `shoukatt_mgnt1` in your database, but since it does not exist it's failing.  You'll either have to restore the table, or reinstall the extension so the table get's recreated.

Answer (score 0):

To print the errors on screen rename the `local.xml.sample` file in `magento_root/errors/` to `local.xml`

These settings allow for errors to be printed onscreen.

Comment: Leaving this change in place on a live Magento e-commerce server is a PCI violation as making the stack trace visible to anyone visiting the site opens up a security hole. Just go read the file...